# Inability to bridge back from Arb to zksync with zksync wallet on Gnosis safe

Tags: gnosis-safe, safe-core-sdk, safe-core, arbitrum, zksync

I bridge about 0.13eth from zksync eth to ARB using jumper bridge.

As you know, zksync users use Arb while bridging in and out. However I can't bridge out back because the feature is not possible yet which the jumper team just told us when we messaged them. But they still kept the feature there which made a lot of people lose their money.

But making bridging in and out in safe with one address created on just like we do on EVM

Please we pleadingly request that this feature should be allowed so that people that bridge from zksync to Arb with their accounts on gnosis safe can bridge back. Just as it's possible between avalanche and optimism.

Because when reached out to gnosis safe team what they said was that it's because of the restrictions from zksync at the moment.

Should Incase any knows what can be done should please provide the information or if any dev from zksync team could help on this .

Break down
I bridge from zksync to Arb but the money has left zksync and now on Arb. But still on the same address
-That is Arb explore with the same address showing the 0.13 eth and still the same zksync address

Answer (score 0):

this does not look like the problem comes from Safe but rather from Jumper bridge. Was a Safe deployed on Arbitrum at this address?

Since zkSync and EVM are not implementing `CREATE` and `CREATE2` the same way, there is currently no way to deploy a Safe deterministically (on a pre-determined address) on zkSync at the moment.

Answer (score -1):

I have the same problem. did you manage to solve it?

i made a bridge inside the safe wallet through the jump dapp, from zksync eth to arbitrum eth, and now i can't reverse it.

Comment: It's better to add it as a comment instead of an answer.